# SMTP ERROR : Could not authenticate - NOT GMAIL, own VPS server

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-14.04, phpmailer, smtp-auth

I was searching on google about 18 hours and my nerves are very bad... even on stackoverflow

First i am student so sorry for my bad english

What I want to do:
I am preparing my new VPS server where I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and also the newest version of postfix to receive and send the E-mails (about 5000 for clients) from this VPS. Also I configured my Postfix..
On my domain I am using the newest PHPMailer as well and PHP 5.5

I want to connect my domain to SMTP on VPS and send email from this VPS to another servers...

My problem:
I was trying a lot of configurations and alternatives and still have this error, my PHP script cannot connect to my SMTP host

My .php file from where I am sending emails:

```
<?php

    require_once("mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    require_once("mailer/class.smtp.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

    $mail->SMTPSecure     = false;
    $mail->Host          = "mail.xxx.cz";
    $mail->SMTPAuth      = true;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->Port          = 587;
    $mail->Username      = "michal@mail.xxx.cz";
    $mail->Password      = "TEST";
    $mail->SMTPDebug      = 3;

    $mail->FromName      = "Michal";
    $mail->From          = "michal@mail.xxx.cz";
    $mail->Subject       = "Newsletter";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->MsgHTML("testing");
    $mail->AddAddress("filfareu@gmail.com");

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    } 
    echo "Message has been sent";

?>
```

My VPS Postfix configuration:
http://fio.filfar.eu/files/Xj4qBxbYsi.png

My SMTP Error log from PHP script (PHPMailer.php - debug mode 3):

```
2016-01-08 12:03:35 Connection: opening to mail.xxx.cz:587, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-01-08 12:03:35 Connection: opened
2016-01-08 12:03:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 vm1xxxx ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
2016-01-08 12:03:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO blog.xxx.cz
2016-01-08 12:03:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vm1xxxx
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-SIZE 10240000
                                      250-VRFY
                                      250-ETRN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250 DSN
2016-01-08 12:03:35 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2016-01-08 12:03:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-01-08 12:03:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
2016-01-08 12:03:35 Connection: closed
2016-01-08 12:03:35 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I am sure that my Username and password are correct, spending hours to that too ...

BIG THANKS to everyone who want to help.
I am out of my energy to solving this problem...

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and base your code on the examples provided with it.

Comment: I have already update it and nothing.. I am going to try, what you wrote lower.. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cross  check your smtp details first.
You can check it online http://smtper.nanogenesis.fr/

Comment: Still nothing. It cannot connect: Failure sending mail.
Unable to connect to the remote server, A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.xx . I dont know, because it connect to the server but SMTP dont work ..

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to port 587 (the SMTP submission protocol port), but your server is not offering either AUTH or STARTTLS commands in its list of capabilities when you connect, so there is no way for your client to authenticate. You need to fix your postfix server config.

Comment: So, I need TLS or SSL security ? I need only simple auth with no security, Should I use another port ? I am using smtp_sasl_auth_enabled = yes so auth should be enable or not ?

Comment: Submitting via port 587 implicitly requires STARTTLS support according to the RFCs. If you don't want to require auth (because your mail server is local), just submit to localhost port 25 without auth, though make sure you're not an open relay